# Error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to boolean

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, getter-setter

I have 6 Buttons and 6 booleans, the Actionhandler should make the boolean, that is for its button, true if it is clicked. To make it easier I made a boolean[] array, but the setter function gives the error:

> "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to boolean" ;

What do I need to set in the setter in ActionListener?

I tried:

- `Var.setKo(true);`
- `Var.setKo(true[i]);`
- `Var.setKo(boolean[i] true);`
- and more

```
        public class Gui {

    static JButton ko[] = new JButton[6];

    public Gui() {

        int y=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ko.length; i++) {
            ko[i] = new JButton();
            ko[i].addActionListener(new ActionHandler());
            ko[i].setBorder(bor);
            if(i==0||i==2||i==4) {
                ko[i].setBounds(650, 200+60*y, 250, 30);
            }else {
                ko[i].setBounds(950, 200+60*y, 250, 30);
                y++;
            }
            jfMenu.add(ko[i]);

        }
    }

    public static JButton[] getKo() {
        return ko;
    }

    public static void setKo(JButton[] ko) {
        Gui.ko = ko;
    }


}
```

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    for (int i = 0; i < Var.getKo().length; i++) {
        if(e.getSource() == Var.getKo()) {
            Var.setKo(true[i]);
        }else {
            Var.getKo()[i] = false;
        }
    }
```

}

```
public class Var {

    static boolean ko[] = new boolean[6];

    public Var() {

        for (int i = 0; i < ko.length; i++) {
            ko[i] = false;
        }

    }
    public static boolean[] getKo() {
        return ko;
    }

    public static void setKo(boolean[] ko) {
        Var.ko = ko;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first Code is the variable class in which the booleans are declarated and set default to false ; the second is in the ActionListener, it contains the problem ; the third one is just for understanding that i have 6 Buttons which all will have an own boolean

Comment: You haven't shown how `ko` is declared, but it must be an array of `JButton` or some superclass thereof, or else you wouldn't be able to assign to it as you do. So you cannot return it as an array of boolean, and you would never want to have a setter that replaced the entire array since you'd lose the references to your buttons. Additionally, `true[i]` isn't remotely close to being valid; a boolean is not an array and cannot be subscripted.

Comment: @DavidConrad I added more Code I hope it will help you ( and others ) understanding the trash I made; I do not have an better solution than do this by an boolean, is there another way of recognizing if a button was pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use the setter here, your array exists, it has initialized, so no need it for it to be set again.

What you need instead is to change the value of some of its indexes. And that can be done by using the getter, to get the reference to the array, and then select the correct index and assign it a value.

Like hereunder

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Var.getKo().length; i++) {
        Var.getKo()[i] = e.getSource() == Var.getKo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I Solved it and there was another little mistake, now it does work like ecpected.